# Как возвращать только часть строки PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица

```
|id|name             |
| 1|Denis Denisov    |
| 2|Andew Andrienko  |
| 3|Nikolai Andrienko|
| 4|Andrew Nikolaev  |
```

Не могу понять как вернуть только имена людей, у которых фамилия Andrienko.
Сейчас только есть вариант с выводом всей ячейки, но как возвращать только имена?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE '% Andrienko';
```

Comment: всё зависит от вашего сервера SQL, используйте функции обработки строк

Comment: СУБД-то какая? а то у каждой - свои функции...

Answer (score 2):

Либо сделать 2 столбца - один для имени, другой для фамилии; тогда запрос будет что-то типо `SELECT name FROM table WHERE surname = 'Andrienko';`

Либо - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 (разбиваешь значение столбца по пробелу и вытаскиваешь первый элемент - это и будет имя)

Comment: Да, STRING_SPLIT то, что нужно, но это получается нужно делать 2 SELECTа? Один в начале (как в моем коде), чтобы выбрать подходящие строки с фамилиями, и один в конце, чтобы уже достать только имена

Comment: @whatgenius предполагаю что запрос должен выглядеть как-то так:
`SELECT STRING_SPLIT(тут нужный код) FROM table WHERE name LIKE '% Andrienko';`

Comment: А почему не работает функция `STRING_SPLIT(name, ' ')`? Вот что выводит `[2022-02-22 16:07:55] [42883] ОШИБКА: функция string_split(unknown, unknown) не существует
[2022-02-22 16:07:55] Подсказка: Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.`

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать CHARINDEX() для поиска пробела:

```
select id, left([name],CHARINDEX(' ', [name], 0) - 1) as firstname from table WHERE [name] LIKE '% Andrienko'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что-то такое я могу предложить

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, ' ') - 1) AS name 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '% Andrienko';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT substring(name, 1, position(' ' in name) - 1) FROM tickets WHERE name LIKE '% Andrienko';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]